# It is possible to print the title of a plot below the x axis?

Tags: pgfplots, captions

i wanted to know if it possible to have the plot's title below the x-axis instead of above.
i attach the plot that i've done:

[image]

and the code for the axis that i used for the graph on the left:

```
 \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=60,axis y line*=left,ymin=9.79,ymax=9.87, xlabel=
{Tempo [ore]}, ylabel={Pressione [bar]},title=\textbf{a)} {$P_{media}$ VS 
$T_{media}$},legend style={draw=none, at={(1,.0)},anchor=south east}]
```

Thank you

Comment: Try add `title style={at={(0.5,0)},anchor=north,yshift=-0.1}` between axis options.

Comment: I wouldn't use the title as a caption. Rather use \subfig or similar, you can also have labels and references

Comment: If you use \begin{axis}[name=myname] you can use anchor points like (myname.south) to attach text nodes (after \end{axis}).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lets summarize and extend above comments. The first and the last (from John Kormylo and mine) propose solution to place graph title as part of graph, the second propose to omit title as part of graph and determine it in subcaption environment:

**Solution 1:**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 ...
 title style={at={(0.5,0)},anchor=north,yshift=-0.1},
 title = ....,
                ]
 ...
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 name=mygraph, % or whatewer
                ]
 ...
 \end{axis}
 \node[anchor=north] at (mygraph.south) { ... title ...};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

**Solution 3a:**

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
    \begin{subcaption}{<width}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 ...
 \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ ... title ...}
\label{subfig:1}
    \end{subcaption}
\hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}
 ...
 \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ ... title ...}
\label{subfig:2}
    \end{subcaption}
\caption{figure caption}
\label{fig:...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Solution 3b:**
In this last solution you also can use `subfig` package instead `subcaption` and its `subfloat` environment:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
    \subfloat[ ... title ... \label{...}]
    {
\begin{tikzpicture}
 ...
 \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\hfil
    \subfloat[ ... title ... \label{...}]
    {
\begin{tikzpicture}
 ...
 \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\caption{figure caption}
\label{fig:...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your clearness. Definetly i've used the 3b option with 'subfig' package and it works!

Comment: Disadvantage of solution 1: cannot insert a `\caption` inside axis titles. Disadvantage of solution 3a/3b: cannot share elements between a common groupplot. Thus, solution 2 was the best for me in the end. :-)